# "Custom" alphabet for DataTables

Tags: web, datatables

Hay, I'm using DataTables and I have an issue. As shown,[on photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PImo.png) I sorted my table by first column, descending. As you can see entities starting on "Ś" and "Ł" are after a "Z". They should be after "S" and "L". Can I add "custom" alphabet or do something about that? Thanks

Comment: If you have not done so already, don't forget to take the [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

You can add the [internationalization](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/intl) configuration option:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/sorting/intl.js"></script>
```

And then you can initialize DataTables with a locale:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // use the 'en' (English) locale:
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.order.intl('en');

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        // your specific initialization here
    } );
} );
```

This results in the following display:

[image]

It replaces the default Unicode sort order with a locale-based order where, for example, letters with diacritics/accents are sorted alongside their unaccented equivalents.

My example uses `en` (English) - but that is probably sufficient for most cases which are based on the Latin (A-Z) alphabet.

If you need something different, take a look at the list of [sorting plug-ins here](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/). There are a lot of options to choose from.

If you need more information about how collation is implemented by DataTables, DataTables uses the JavaScript [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator) object.